# Using table() to create 3 variable frequency table in R

Tags: r, frequency

I'm new to R and seeking some help.  I understand the following problem is fairly simple and have looked for similar questions. None give quite the answer I'm looking for - any help would be appreciated.

**The problem:**

Producing a frequency table using the `table()` function for three variables with data in the format:

```
    Var1    Var2   Var3
1   0        1        0
2   0        1        0
3   1        1        1
4   0        0        1
```

Where, 0 = "No" and 1 = "Yes"

And the final table is in the following format with variables and values labelled:

```
           Var3
           Yes   No
Var1  Yes   1     0
      No    1     2
Var2  Yes   1     2
      No    1     0
```

**What I have tried so far:**

Using the following code I'm able to produce a 2 variable table, with labels for the variables but not for the values (ie. No and Yes).

```
table(data$Var1, data$Var3, dnn = c("Var1", "Var3"))
```

It looks like this:

```
      Var3
Var1  0  1
   0  2  1
   1  0  1
```

In trying to label the row and column values (0 = No and 1= Yes) I understand `row.names` and `responseName` can be used, however the following attempt to label row names gives an `all arguments must have the same length` error.

```
> table(data$Var1, data$Var2, dnn = c("Var1", "Var2"), row.names = c("No", "Yes"))
```

I have also tried using `ftable()` however the shape of the table produced using code below is not correct resulting in incorrect frequencies for the problem.  The issue with labeling row & col values persists.

```
> ftable(data$Var1, data$Var2, data$Var3, dnn = c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3"))
      Var3  0  1
Var1 Var2             
0     0     0  1
      1     2  0
1     0     0  0
      1     0  1
```

Any help in using `table()` to produce a table of the shape desired would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Convert your data to factors first to take care of the labelling issue: `dat <- data.frame(lapply(dat, factor, levels=1:0, labels=c("Yes","No")))`

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful and is perfect for resolving the labeling problem.

Answer (score 6):

You could try `tabular` from `library(tables)` after changing the labels as showed by @thelatemail

```
library(tables)
data[] <- lapply(data, factor, levels=1:0, labels=c('Yes', 'No'))
tabular(Var1+Var2~Var3, data=data)

 #         Var3   
 #         Yes  No
 #Var1  Yes 1    0 
 #      No  1    2 
 #Var2  Yes 1    2 
 #      No  1    0
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(Var1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Var2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L), Var3 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to probably use the `reshape2` package. Firstly you will need to convert your numeric information to factors so that it doesn't treat it as a number.

```
data$Var1 <- as.factor(data$Var1)
data$Var2 <- as.factor(data$Var2)
data$Var3 <- as.factor(data$Var3)
```

Then you can easily just apply `table(data)` to get the information you want. If you really want to transform it in the format you specified, then pull it as a `data.frame` and then transform it as required:

```
df <- as.data.frame(table(data))
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, Var1+Var2 ~ Var3)
```

This as the output:

```
  Var1 Var2 0 1
1    0    0 0 1
2    0    1 2 0
3    1    0 0 0
4    1    1 0 1
```

---

**EDIT**: You can just use `ftable` on the data frame once its all factors:

```
> ftable(data)
          Var3 0 1
Var1 Var2         
0    0         0 1
     1         2 0
1    0         0 0
     1         0 1
```

Comment: Thanks @chappers, where would I get the reshape2 package from?  I'm using Rstudio and it is not available in the default list of packages.

Comment: i just realised you can just use `ftable` to get the same result (see my edit). If you're interested in `reshape2`, just try `install.packages("reshape2")` in the console and it will install it for you automatically

Comment: @chappers - the `ftable` solution is not quite the same - the answer gives a count of `Var1 x Var2 x Var3` not `Var1 x Var3` joined with `Var2 x Var3`

Comment: thats right @thelatemail, this is specified in the question.  Also in looking at the shape of the output using reshape2, this is not the specific shape I'm looking for.

Comment: @akrun the desired shape is defined within the question (the 2nd code block).

Comment: @AlisonBennett  Okay, thanks, the several code blocks distracted me.

Comment: @chappers Regarding converting to `factor` , i am not sure if that is needed here unless you are changing the labels as thelatemail mentioned in the comments.  I get the same `dcast` output without converting explicitly to factor as `str(as.data.frame(table(data)))` will get the columns var1:var3 as factors

Comment: Oh i got confused by the code blocks like @akrun as well!